# Delete a group of name using checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm having problem where if I checked all the checkbox, it only deleted the checkbox on the bottom, not all of it. Any help?

```js
function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[9].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        var name = table.rows[i].cells[i].innerHTML;
        document.forms[0].action = "A.do?event=delete&name=" + name;
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }
      document.forms[0].submit();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert("No item selected for deletion");
  }

}
```

```html
<td><input type="button" class="btnNormal" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="box"></td>
```

Comment: Variable ***i*** is used by the for-loop, you can't/shouldn't change that value since it will be incremented by the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Function with

```
function deleteRow(tableID)
{
    try
    {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for(var i=rowCount; i>=0; i--) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[9].childNodes[0];
      if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          var name = table.rows[i].cells[i].innerHTML;
          document.forms[0].action="A.do?event=delete&name="+name;
          table.deleteRow(i);
        }
      }
      document.forms[0].submit();
     }catch(e) {alert("No item selected for deletion");}
}
```

Remember:

1. When you are deleting items from array. always start your for loop
   in decreasing order. Because if start it with increasing order index
   will change after each delete.
2. why you are submitting form inside for loop. It is wrong I think. submit it after completion of For Loop.